# Implementation of numpy.polyfit and numpy.polyval in C++ with Armadillo

Tags: python, c++, numpy, linear-regression, armadillo

I'm trying to reproduce the results of [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and the following application of [`numpy.polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval) in C++ by using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).

This is my attempt:

```
using namespace arma;

vec fastLm(const vec& y,
           const mat& X,
           int order)
{
  mat extended_X(X);
  
  // Column bind the higher order regressors to the initial matrix
  for(int i = 2; i < order + 1; ++i)
  {
    extended_X = join_rows(extended_X, pow(X, i));
  }
  
  // Join another column, made of '1', in order to have the intercept
  extended_X = join_rows(mat(X.n_rows, 1, fill::ones), extended_X);
  
  // Solve the linear regression by OLS
  colvec coef = solve(extended_X, y);

  // Return the fit
  return extended_X * coef;
}
```

and I would expect to get the same results as:

```
import numpy as np

def fastLm(y, X, order):

    # Fit the polynomial regression
    rg = np.polyfit(X, y, order)

    # Return the fit
    C = np.polyval(rg, X)

    return C
```

However, my tests show discrepancies and weird results whose cause I'm having difficulties to find and debug. Could you please tell me if my "translation" is correct or fix it?

Comment: Why reimplement? Armadillo already has the [polyfit](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#polyfit) and [polyval](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#polyval) functions.

Comment: Really? Didn't know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it all looks good, have tried your function with

```
int main()
{
  mat x=linspace(0,1,5);
  vec y=1/(1+x);
  y.print("Y");
  mat Yhat = fastLm(y,x,3);
  Yhat.print("Yhat");
}
```

giving the results

```
Y
   1.0000
   0.8000
   0.6667
   0.5714
   0.5000
Yhat
   0.9998
   0.8008
   0.6654
   0.5722
   0.4998
```

And the corresponding result with your python code is

```
[1.         0.8        0.66666667 0.57142857 0.5       ]
[0.99979592 0.80081633 0.66544218 0.5722449  0.49979592]
```

... and Matlab

```
>> Y
Y =

   1.00000   0.80000   0.66667   0.57143   0.50000

>> Yhat
Yhat =

   0.99980   0.80082   0.66544   0.57224   0.49980

>>
```